# Connect 2 queries to 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

I have code like this:

```
$id = 5;
$a = 1;
$b = ($a === 2 ? 1 : 2);

DB::table('table')->where('id', $id)->where('value', $a)->update(['new_value' => 1]);
DB::table('table')->where('id', $id)->where('value', $b)->update(['new_value' => 2]);
```

Is it possible to make this 2 queries in 1?

Comment: Thanks for answer @tanaydin. I think same, but i want to know it's possible or not.

Comment: You can do it with of course - using `WHEN .. THEN`, you can dynamically build that query if there is variable number of those `values`. @JosephSilber gave you the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the query builder for this. Use `DB::statement` instead:

```php
DB::statement('UPDATE table SET new_value = CASE 
               WHEN value = ? THEN ?
               WHEN value = ? THEN ?
               END WHERE id = ?', [
    $a, 1,
    $b, 2,
    $id,
]);
```

Comment: this is the way to go, I would just add an `ELSE new_value` as fallback. And btw you can do it with `Query\Builder` simply providing `DB::raw(' case ...')` to the `update()` method.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - The `update` method expects an array.

Comment: @JosephSilber yeah, but that doesn't stop you from adding them manually straight away.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - and how would you protect against SQL injection?

Comment: @JosephSilber You didn't get my point. Just add the bindings manually with `addBinging(s)` method.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - Where exactly would you add it? [The query builder doesn't accept bindings for `update`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L32-L43).

Comment: @JosephSilber It's the same as `select`. Most straightforward: `DB::table(..)->where(..)->setBindings(['value1', 'value2'], 'select')->update(['column' => DB::raw('case when X then ? when Y then ? else column end')]);`

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - That's just confusing as hell. I don't see what you gain with this over a regular `DB::statement()`.

Comment: You know, that's more of an academic discussion, on whether you can or can't. Opinion vary, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql query you can achieve by below query:

```
$mysqlQuery = "UPDATE table1
SET new_value = IF(id=".$id ." AND value=".$a.",1, IF(id=".$id." AND value=".$b.",2,new_value))";

Note:If you want this mysql query to be written in some framework specific query then you can convert it as per your framework syntax or documentation.
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, not with laravel fluent. There are 2 different queries with different update values. You can however make it into a reusable function.

```
public function updateNewValue($id, $value, $newValue)
{
    return DB::table('table')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->where('value', $value)
        ->update(['new_value' => $newValue]);
}
```

Or, you can combine it into one with a switch statement depending on the `new_value`:

```
$query = DB::table('table')->where('id', $id);

switch($newValue)
{
    case 1:
        return $query->where('value', $a)->update(['new_value' => $newValue]);
    case 2:
        return $query->where('value', $b)->update(['new_value' => $newValue]);
}
```